# Php sessions don't work after htaccess rewriterule

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, mod-rewrite, session-variables

I have a booking system that i'm trying to set up. I want to use the same functions for all customers. I have set up htaccess rewriterule to make it look like all the files are run from
www.mydomain.com/web-book/customerX/index.php
, but in fact the files are located in the web-book folder. This is just for nice displaying and for giving each customer an easy link to their bookings.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([_a-zA-Z-]+)\.php$ /web-book/$2.php?site=$1
```

I'm also moving my css/images with the same technique working fine. javascripts working fine. Everything is good except the php Sessions.

THE PROBLEM: The php $_Session variables won't work, meaning i can't log in or do anything involving sessions.
There must be something that i'm missing? I wan't my session vars to the accessible all over mydomain.com if possible???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you append PHP's Session-IDs to Querystring? If so, try to use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([_a-zA-Z-]+)\.php$ /web-book/$2.php?site=$1 [QSA]
```

This will preserve any Get-Variable in Querystring, including Session IDs.

Comment: I just found out...2min ago that i forgot that. Thanks for helping anyway, problem solved :) I feeel so stupid sometimes ;)

Comment: I've used your rule RewriteRule /subfolder/^index\.php$ - [QSA] but have still PHP $_SESSION issue - I can't unset single session var.

Answer (score 0):

Check if don't have a conflicting `php.ini` file located at the root folder.

I unintentionally copied the `php.ini` file from my local server to the remote server and this prevent `$_SESSION` to be shared between my root directory and the sub directories.